# Replace a string in a file by matching a string

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file as below

```
$vnic = "ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrqwrgvdjuhhm55plktmxx7gz723mpcpuspa5rdmtd7spi5egww2ua";

$nsg1 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaawzei5sybgstutahgils36oohlvlpz76f7zdl7hvbi5oqzxtiw7va";
$nsg2 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaa6kjmsfkyxfkcorcys6zrgxtyjquwy7mla27n2hqdl4aqubkgd6dq";
$nsg3 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaavar4pef6iqnwuui6qjawxdz4ui3vs4tyges64isde6wufwi44cqa";
$nsg4 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaaaaxzwne6pnzzjku2ld6m77dt7lr2m2qc4ix3mmrzx5baux5s5n7a";
$nsg5 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaatxe7bmd5n24don5473nbutcg34some672big7iowyk5f7yjfnmrq";
```

I want to change the value of `$vnic`,`$nsg1`,`$nsg2`,`$nsg3`,`$nsg4`,`$nsg5` whenever required. How can I do it using `sed` or `awk` as I want to use it in a bash script which will update it every day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` you can try this:

```bash
sed -i "/\$some_field/s/\".*\"/\"$some_val\"/" file
```

For example, if you want to change the value of `$vnic` you can use:

```bash
some_val="fuzz"
sed -i "/\$vnic/s/\".*\"/\"$some_val\"/" file
```

With `/\$vnic/` the sed command selects the lines that matches with `$vnic`. With `s/\".*\"/\"$some_val\"/` will substitute in the matched line any value between double quotes`"` (including these one) with the value you have in `$some_val`.

For example, if the file contents:

```
$vnic = "ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrqwrgvdjuhhm55plktmxx7gz723mpcpuspa5rdmtd7spi5egww2ua";
$nsg1 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaawzei5sybgstutahgils36oohlvlpz76f7zdl7hvbi5oqzxtiw7va";
$nsg2 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaa6kjmsfkyxfkcorcys6zrgxtyjquwy7mla27n2hqdl4aqubkgd6dq";
$nsg3 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaavar4pef6iqnwuui6qjawxdz4ui3vs4tyges64isde6wufwi44cqa";
$nsg4 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaaaaxzwne6pnzzjku2ld6m77dt7lr2m2qc4ix3mmrzx5baux5s5n7a";
$nsg5 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaatxe7bmd5n24don5473nbutcg34some672big7iowyk5f7yjfnmrq";
```

And you apply `some_val=fuzz ; sed -i "/\$vnic/s/\".*\"/\"$some_val\"/" file`   the file will be updated with this:

```
$vnic = "fuzz";
$nsg1 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaawzei5sybgstutahgils36oohlvlpz76f7zdl7hvbi5oqzxtiw7va";
$nsg2 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaa6kjmsfkyxfkcorcys6zrgxtyjquwy7mla27n2hqdl4aqubkgd6dq";
$nsg3 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaavar4pef6iqnwuui6qjawxdz4ui3vs4tyges64isde6wufwi44cqa";
$nsg4 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaaaaxzwne6pnzzjku2ld6m77dt7lr2m2qc4ix3mmrzx5baux5s5n7a";
$nsg5 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaatxe7bmd5n24don5473nbutcg34some672big7iowyk5f7yjfnmrq";
```

If you want to replace any other value you can use `-e` option in `sed` to avoid using the same command multiple times, for example:

```bash
some_val2=fuzz
some_val=buzz
sed  -e "/\$vnic/s/\".*\"/\"$some_val\"/"  -e "/\$nsg1/s/\".*\"/\"$some_val2\"/"
```

and the content of the file would be:

```
$vnic = "buzz";
$nsg1 = "fuzz";
$nsg2 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaa6kjmsfkyxfkcorcys6zrgxtyjquwy7mla27n2hqdl4aqubkgd6dq";
$nsg3 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaavar4pef6iqnwuui6qjawxdz4ui3vs4tyges64isde6wufwi44cqa";
$nsg4 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaaaaxzwne6pnzzjku2ld6m77dt7lr2m2qc4ix3mmrzx5baux5s5n7a";
$nsg5 = "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaatxe7bmd5n24don5473nbutcg34some672big7iowyk5f7yjfnmrq";
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @ph3ro A pleasure!